# Problem adapting my dataframe to a specific form

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a very big problem I would like help with.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Route | Day | Time | Tickets Sold | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SD - LA | 04-01-22 | 8:00 | 45 | 210 |
| SD - LA | 04-05-22 | 8:00 | 89 | 293 |
| SD - LA | 04-06-22 | 8:00 | 60 | 252 |
| SD - LA | 04-07-22 | 8:00 | 91 | 310 |
| SD - LA | 04-09-22 | 8:00 | 129 | 470 |
| SD - SF | 04-01-22 | 10:00 | 43 | 200 |
| SD - SF | 04-05-22 | 10:00 | 52 | 240 |
| SD - SF | 04-06-22 | 10:00 | 71 | 320 |
| SD - SF | 04-07-22 | 10:00 | 67 | 300 |
| SD - SF | 04-09-22 | 10:00 | 70 | 310 |

I would like to transform it to something like this:

| Route | Time | TS 04-01-22 | R 04-01-22 | TS 04-05-22 | R 04-05-22 | TS 04-06-22 | R 04-06-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SD-LA | 8:00 | 45 | 210 | 89 | 293 | 60 | 252 |
| SD-SF | 10:00 | 43 | 200 | 52 | 240 | 71 | 320 |

Where R = Revenue and TS = Tickets Sold

I would like to include all the dates!

I know something like a reshape would work.. but honestly I don't know how to do it, because I want my columns to have different names

Thanks in advance, all help is appreciated!

I want to do this basically because I want a time series that shows me how the tickets sold and the revenue have evolved during time!

Answer (score 1):

Here a way to get the columns ordered correctly (since the order of your dates in format `%m-%d-%y` might be messed up at year change):

```
df.rename({"Revenue": "R", "Tickets Sold": "TS"}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.pivot_table(index=["Route", "Time"], columns="Day", values=["TS", "R"]).reset_index()
# Switching to single index columns:
df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns]

sorted_col_date = ["Route", "Time"] + sorted(df.columns[2:], key = lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(x.split()[1], format="%m-%d-%y"), -ord(x.split()[0][0])))
df = df.reindex(columns=sorted_col_date)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Route   Time  TS 04-01-22  R 04-01-22  TS 04-05-22  R 04-05-22  TS 04-06-22  R 04-06-22  TS 04-07-22  R 04-07-22  TS 04-09-22  R 04-09-22
0  SD - LA   8:00           45         210           89         293           60         252           91         310          129         470
1  SD - SF  10:00           43         200           52         240           71         320           67         300           70         310
```

Comment: wowwww!!!! you are so right!!!! But I am having a very small problem.. how can I change this code so that there is no error? my date column is in format `datetime` and apparently you are taking it as a string! I already try to convert it to a string with `df.date = df['date'].astype(str)` but it is not working :(

Comment: That's because your column is called `Day` :D

Comment: sorry, my bad! I just wrote it wrong here.. I am doing it correctly `df.Day = df['Day'].astype(str)` and it does work.. but it tells me there is an error

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, datetime.date found`

Comment: Try printing `df.dtypes` before and after the conversion. What line does raise the error? Also be sure to convert *before* pivoting

Answer (score 0):

You want to [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the df:

```py
header = ['Route', 'Day', 'Time', 'Tickets Sold', 'Revenue']

rows = [
    ['SD - LA', '04-01-22', '8:00', '45', '210'],
    ['SD - LA', '04-05-22', '8:00', '89', '293'],
    ['SD - LA', '04-06-22', '8:00', '60', '252'],
    ['SD - LA', '04-07-22', '8:00', '91', '310'],
    ['SD - LA', '04-09-22', '8:00', '129', '470'],
    ['SD - SF', '04-01-22', '10:00', '43', '200'],
    ['SD - SF', '04-05-22', '10:00', '52', '240'],
    ['SD - SF', '04-06-22', '10:00', '71', '320'],
    ['SD - SF', '04-07-22', '10:00', '67', '300'],
    ['SD - SF', '04-09-22', '10:00', '70', '310']
]

# store your data as df
df = pd.DataFrame(
    rows, 
    columns=header
)

# PIVOT!!!
df = df.pivot(
    values = ['Tickets Sold', 'Revenue'],
    index=['Route', 'Time'], 
    columns = 'Day'
).reset_index()

# rename columns
df.columns = [' '.join(c) for c in df.columns]

df
```

Comment: it gives me this error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (290, 3), indices imply (2, 3)`

Comment: Weird. The other answer that copied mine seems to work though?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from Matt's solution

```
df2=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Route','Time'], columns='Day', 
            values=['TS','R'], aggfunc=np.sum).sort_values(by='Day', axis=1) 
df2.columns = list(map(" ".join, df2.columns.values))
df2=df2.reset_index()
```

```
Route   Time    R 04-01-22  TS 04-01-22 R 04-05-22  TS 04-05-22 R 04-06-22  TS 04-06-22 R 04-07-22  TS 04-07-22 R 04-09-22  TS 04-09-22
0   SD - LA 8:00    210 45  293 89  252 60  310 91  470 129
1   SD - SF 10:00   200 43  240 52  320 71  300 67  310 70
```

PS: Not sure how to make the output comes as it shows in notebook